# compare row values in Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, data-analysis

I want to iterate through all rows of a Dataframe and check if the string in the column `row['Name']`is present in the productmapping dictionary. If yes, I want to get the respective key and append it to my list. However, currently it iterates more times than it should and I get all Not Founds.

```
mylist = []
for index, row in newdf.iterrows():
    for key, value in productmapping.items():
        if key in row['Name'].lower():
            mylist.append(key)
            break
        else:
            mylist.append('Not Found')
print(mylist)
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample, 2-4 rows? [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @a125 What ``productionmapping`` looks like? Are you searching for the presence of ``row['Name']`` in the keys or values? From your example it looks like you do it the other way around: check if ``key`` is present in ``row['Name']``.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if key is present in the row as a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65989406/check-if-key-is-present-in-the-row-as-a-substring)

Answer (score 0):

Use df.apply(function_name, axis=1). You will going through dataframe only once.

```
dictionary={"key": 1}
array=[]

def function(x):
   if x["column"] in dictionary:
     array.append((x["column"],dictionary[x["column"]])) # tuple of key,value

df.apply(function, axis=1)
```