# check if key is present in the row as a substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dictionary

```
myDict = {
'apple': 'FULL FORM',
'ball' : 'NEW'
}
```

and then a dataframe:

```
myCol
..
new apple
netball
hello
```

I want to iterate over all rows of col `myCol` and all the keys of my dictionary to see if any of my keys are present as a substring in the row value. If yes, I want to obtain the key value and append it to a list. For example, the key value 'apple' comes as a substring in my first row 'new apple', so I want to extract the key value 'apple'

I am trying this but the iteration doesn't seem to work since I get all 'Not Founds'

```
myList = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for key, value in myDict.items():  
            if key in row['myCol'].lower():
                mylist.append(key)
        else:
            print(row['myCol'].lower())
            mylist.append('Not Found')
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should be changed with `break`:

```
myList = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for key, value in myDict.items():  
            if key in row['myCol'].lower():
                myList.append(key)
                break
        else:
            print(row['myCol'].lower())
            myList.append('Not Found')
print(myList) 
['apple', 'ball', 'Not Found']
```

Or use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by keys of dictionary with join by `|` for regex `or`, if no match is generated missing value, so replace it by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and convert `Series` to list:

```
myList = (df['myCol'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(myDict.keys())})', expand=False, case=False)
                     .fillna('Not Found')
                     .tolist())

print(myList) 
['apple', 'ball', 'Not Found']
```